# Events and other stuff does not work in general

Tags: jquery, css, html, button

I got my static HTML(5) file with jQuery (latest release), and nothing that I tried got my jQuery Code running.

origin html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BynGame</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jQuery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(jInit);
function jInit(){
    $.('#thebutton').click( function() { alert("HIT THE WALL");} );
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div><span>{{ login }}</span></div>
<div class="navbar">
<a href="/"><span>Home</span></a>
<a href="/submit"><span>Neuen Eintrag erstellen</span></a>
<a href="/all"><span>Channel&#252;bersicht</span></a>
<a href="/register"><span>Registrieren</span></a>
</div>
<div>
<span id="thefield"></span>
<br />
<div id="hitme">Click Me or Hit Me</div>
<div id="blu" style="background:blue;">
<button id="thebutton" type="submit">
Push The Button!    
</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked W3C.org and it occured NO validation error. (Even no related warnings)

Now changing between `$.(document).ready(jInit)` and `$.(document).ready(jInit())` makes no difference.

- Putting `.ready()` before or after
  jInit() does not affect the code.
- Putting something different into
  jInit() does not affect the code.
- Renaming jInit() to something else....
- Using different jQuery refs......
- simply calling `$.get("#thebutton').click( function() { that I wrote; });` doesn't work

The only thing that works is: (without any other code in front of it, otherwise it seems to be broken)

`$(document).ready(function() {alert("bla");});`

Am I missing some basic Javascript Syntax?
I am completely frustrated... because implementing JS into my Project is really essentiall and I turned to try to get the simpliest stuff to work, but event this fails.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I am a complete dumbass :) It mus me $("XPATHLIKESYNTAX") and not $.(......)

Comment: For future reference, please do not use swear words in any content you post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$('#thebutton') instead of $.('#thebutton')

Comment: @Andy's correct here. You appear to be using `$.` in a lot of your examples, but that's incorrect; jquery only needs `$`

Comment: Jep, but it seems that jQuery events only work if I set them after $(document).ready() occured.